# How to pass multidimensional array from PHP to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get array value from JSON string, and I do the work with `json_decode` PHP.

```
<?php
$jsonContent=file_get_contents('http://megarkarsa.com/gpsjson.php');
$jsonDecoded=json_decode($jsonContent,true);
foreach($jsonEncoded['BMS'] as $p){
echo '
ID: '.$p['id'].'
Tipe: '.$p['type'].'
';
echo "<br>";
?>
```

The PHP code works, and give the result of array from JSON string. 
And this is my Javascript code

```
<script>
var bmsdata = <?php echo $jsonDecoded ?>;
alert(bmsdata["1"].id); // For check, i want to see the id of row 1
</script>
```

But nothing was shown up.
Am i doing right so far? Or i missing something to pass the value from PHP to Javascript? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work, as I lookup JSON at http://megarkarsa.com/gpsjson.php ;)

```
<script>
var bmsdata = <?php echo json_encode($jsonDecoded); ?>;
alert(bmsdata.BMS["1"].id); // For check, i want to see the id of row 1
</script>
```

You just forgot 'BMS' key ;)

Comment: Sob. I am just laughing to my self at this time. :'D Very thank you! That answers the problem. Miss a simple thing can ruin a whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

`$jsonDecoded` is the decoded json.

Please change

```
var bmsdata = <?php echo $jsonDecoded ?>;
```

to

```
var bmsdata = <?php echo json_encode($jsonDecoded); ?>;
```

or use the already exisiting variable `$jsonContent`:

```
var bmsdata = <?php echo $jsonContent; ?>;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, i tried to change the echo line, but same like before, it didn't give me any result. Or maybe i'm doing it wrong or what?

Comment: Have you already tried `var bmsdata = <?php echo json_encode($jsonDecoded); ?>;`? Is `$jsonDecoded` defined in your javascript part where you are trying to use it?

Comment: yes. And the reason it didn't give any result, simply just because i missed a single key at alert initiation. And, yes, i did change the echo line (remove the `json_encode` or `json_decode`) to echo the value of `$jsonContent` directly. I found the `encode` or `decode` is not necessary for my case. Very thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're injecting a decoded, PHP-representation of the data into your javascript. You probably (if you want to continue doing it this way) want to echo the encoded version (`jsonContent`) instead.

Ultimately, you might want to rethink the approach. Fetching the data via ajax is often an easier way to work with it, since you don't need to worry about writing bare javascript via php, which has all sorts of escaping issues to get right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to echo the encoded version, but didn't give me any result. It's weird. Can you point me any example explanation to fetch the data via ajax? thank you